# Redirect ip address to https

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https

I am using Ubuntu and Nginx.

I have my site hosted under SSL protection.

If I type in the domain name in a browser without the 's' in 'https' in will redirect to 'https'.
But if I type in the IP address of the domain name it will not redirect to 'https'.  It iwll just show in the address bar 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I thought this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

would solve this buy it does not.

Yours Novice...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another server section with the IP address as server_name- You better make the server name also explicit for your domain name (instead of _). Then redirect from the new server section (IP-Address) to the domain name (same thing you did with port 80).

For example:

```
server {
    server_name 12.34.56.178;

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

...and do not forget to restart nginx with `systemctl restart nginx`

Have you tried it like that and restarted your browser to test it? It is sometimes hard to debug stuff when there is a browser cache. Therefore I prefer to use `wget -O- http://12.34.56.78` or `curl -o- http://12.34.56.78` for testing.

Comment: Hi, did not work I am afraid. The ipaddress still shows in the address bar and it still does not redirect to https